# Best metric to measure histogram quality

Tags: statistics, covariance

I'm working on a script that generates histograms for images. It first takes a histogram of all pixels, and then tries various distributions of sample pixels, such as - a grid of pixels, horizontal stripes, diagonal cross...

The idea is that when it's used in embedded system, you need fast method of getting histogram, and fewer pixels = less work.

Here are some example histograms

**Reference - all pixels**
Pixels: 65536
[image]

**Grid**
Pixels: 841
Chi squared: 0.05546
[image]

**Diagonals**
Pixels: 512
Chi squared: 0.1213
[image]

Now I have the histograms, but I need to determine their "quality" - some good metric that will give clear results. So far I tried chi squared test, but I'm not sure it's the right choice.

Also I'd like to calculate a "score" factor, based on number of pixels, and quality of histogram. The fewer pixels and better quality, the higher score. I tried multiplying chi squared by number of pixels, but it skewed the results weirdly (lower score would then mean better).

Maybe instead of calculating score, I could make some plot of the two values?

(I'll run this on a larger set of images, so the scores can be averaged)

Comment: if you don't get an answer here, maybe the signal processing or statistics stackexchange could help.

Comment: i'm speaking out of turn here, but why don't you calculate a squared error (or something) on the difference between a reference histogram (like the 1st) and the lower quality ones?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that if it doesn't work here.

Comment: Sorry, i don't know what mse is... I tried squaring differences but it didn't work too good. Basically any metric will do, I'm not really sure which one to use though